# get values foreach loop from php user defined function

Tags: php, function, foreach-loop-container

I hae a question regarding PHP function(s). Been googling all around but can't find a satisfying answer to my problem.

I try to get vales from a foreach loop that's inside a selfmade function:

```
function get_gemeente_by_id($gemeente_id)
{
    global $db;

    // Omzetten van integer (id) naar string (name)
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM gemeenten WHERE id = {$gemeente_id}");
    $query->execute();

    foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $gemeente)
    {
        $district       = $gemeente->district;
        $congregation   = $gemeente->gemeente;
    }
}
```

Running the query straight at the pagetop it works fine. But I want to use the values created within my function to echo it out like so:

I call my function:

```
get_gemeente_by_id($_SESSION['gemeente_id']);
```

and want to echo out the values from the query inside the function.

```
<?= $district; ?> and <?= $congregation; ?>
```

I get an error saying: "Notice: Undefined variable: district in http://localhost/etc"

Hpe someone can help me out. I don't a ot of code in my pages and trying with function to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should return array by your function try this:

```
function get_gemeente_by_id($gemeente_id)
{
   global $db;
   $arr = array()

// Omzetten van integer (id) naar string (name)
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM gemeenten WHERE id = {$gemeente_id}");
$query->execute();

foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $gemeente)
{
    $arr['district'][]  = $gemeente->district;
    $arr['congregation'][]   = $gemeente->gemeente;
}
return $arr
}
```

and when you call the function :

```
$arr = get_gemeente_by_id($_SESSION['gemeente_id']);
foreach ($arr as $dist_con=>$b){
   foreach($b as $a=>$c){
   echo $dist_con.$a."=".$c
    }
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you solution:

```
// get_gemeente_by_id function
function get_gemeente_by_id($gemeente_id)
{
   global $db;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM gemeenten WHERE id =?;");
$query->execute(array($gemeente_id));
return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// Call to function and get associative array with expected data
$arr = get_gemeente_by_id($_SESSION['gemeente_id']);
foreach ($arr as $dist_con=>$b){
   foreach($b as $a=>$c){
   echo $dist_con.$a."=".$c
    }
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Also to much code. Isn't there a way to return the results of my foreach loop within that function? I mean .. I already have the 2 strings $district and $congegation. How can I echo them outside the function?

Comment: Return an array is more reusable than echo specific string, I suggest you to define functions that you could reuse them in future.